# how to keep the session when browser closed in codeigniter3?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently i am using codeigniter3 which i am storing my session driver in database.
Session should not destroy on browser close.
When user clicks the logout button only then should the session get destroyed.
How to achieve it in codeigniter3?

Please give me any solutions.

This is my config file

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 0;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

In the previous version, Codeigniter had `sess_expire_on_close` in the config file but now they have removed it.
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Are you still loading/autoloading the `session` library? Is your `encryption_key` set in config.php`?`

Answer (score 2):

add this line in your `.htaccess` file,

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10000 //10000 is in seconds. You can change it.
```

or in config file,

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 10000;// this is in seconds.
```

Comment: according to codeigniter3 the sess_expire_on_close no more usage

Comment: sorry, i still use `codeigniter2.X` just increase the session expirationn time.

Comment: I would place 86,400 seconds, to ensure that at least lasts an active day as CI3 does not have the configuration which does not expire when the browser is due to changes made throughout the library.